# Command line to start two Excel files in parallel processes

Tags: microsoft-excel, command-line

I know how to start two Excel files in sequence:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\excel.exe" /x "C:\A.xlsx"
timeout /t 10
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\excel.exe" /x "C:\B.xlsx"
```

by doing so, `A.xlsm` need be closed before `B.xlsm` can be opened.

I also know how to start two Excel files in parallel:

```
start C:\A.xlsx
timeout /t 10
start C:\B.xlsx
```

by doing so the two Excel files are opened at the same time, sharing one Excel process.

How can I use command line to start two Excel processes, one for `A.xlsx`, and the other for `B.xlsx`? It seems the command line switch `/x` doesn't help.

Comment: Why not the combination of the two solutions? `start "C:\program files (x86)....excel.exe" /x "C:\A.xlsx"
`timeout /t 10
`start "C:\program...

Comment: @djsmiley2k that doesn't work on my machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct that you need to use the `/X` [command-line option for Excel](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Command-line-switches-for-Excel-c6f24136-e80c-4de9-a0ca-d5c68792cc6f?ctt=1&CorrelationId=f9d0bb7e-f478-4ea8-9d78-0a30bbc61138&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&ocmsassetID=HA102919739). You're likely having trouble because of the syntax of the [Start](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770297(v=ws.11).aspx) command.

First of all, here's the correct command to start two separate instances of Excel, each with a workbook you specify.

```
start "title" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\EXCEL.EXE" /X C:\A.xlsx
start "title" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\EXCEL.EXE" /X C:\B.xlsx
```

Notice the extra `"title"` parameter on the Start command. This extra parameter is required in order to prevent the Start command from interpreting your fully-qualified pathname to Excel.exe as a title for a new Command Prompt Window.

#### Why add the extra "title" parameter to Start?

The Start command accepts an optional "Title" parameter, which can be used to start a new Command Prompt window with a custom title.  For example the command `Start "My New Window"` will start a new Command Prompt window with the title "My New Title".

Therefore, when you run the command :

```
Start "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\EXCEL.EXE" /X C:\A.xlsx
```

The Start command interprets the portion in double-quotes to be the Title paremeter. As a result, the only portion of your command that Start actually executes is:

```
/X C:\A.xlsx
```

Which isn't a valid command.